# How to connect web3 contract with flutter

Tags: flutter, solidity, flutter-web, web3dart

I want to create a web d-App with flutter. I use [flutter_web3](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_web3) to connect to a metamask wallet on the browser with this code:

```
  final access = await ethereum!.requestAccount();
  if (access.isNotEmpty) currentAddress = access.first;
```

It connects successfully and I can get the address of the account. also I have these functions in solidity:

```
pragma solidity ^0.8.0;
contract Money {
uint public money = 0;

function getMoney() public view returns(uint256) {
    return money;
}

function updateMoney() external {
    money += 1;
}
}
```

Also, I have the contract address, RPC URL, and an abi.json file. So, How can I call getMoney function and updateMoney function with the contract?